# RethinkDB connection "must be open" but never gets closed

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, hapi.js, rethinkdb-javascript

I'm using RethinkDB together with hapi.js in Node.js. My main application passes an open connection to a hapi.js plugin. Using the connection inside the main-script works fine, but running something inside the plugin throws the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection ReqlDriverError: First argument to `run` must be an open connection.
```

I tried to figure out if the connection gets closed, but non of the added listeners fire.

```
connection.addListener('connect', () => { console.log('!!connect') })
connection.addListener('close', () => { console.log('!!closed') })
connection.addListener('timeout', () => { console.log('!!timeout') })
connection.addListener('error', () => { console.log('!!error') })
```

I can confirm the the event listers are working in general as calling `connection.close()` manually outputs `!!closed`.

I asked the hapi.js community [on GitHub](https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/182) if a passed object will be passed to plugins as a copy, but that's actually not the case.

Here's the code throwing the error:

```
console.log(server.root.app.connection) // {…} === connection
console.log(server.root.app.connection.open) // true

r.table('records').group('siteLocation').count().run(server.root.app.connection, (err, cursor) => {

    ...

})
```

To sum it up:

- Connection should be open as it never gets closed
- (Inside the plugin:) Can't get data from the database as RethinkDB says that the `First argument to 'run' must be an open connection.`

Is there any way to find out why the connection is **not** open anymore?

RethinkDB version: 2.1.5
hapi.js version: 11.1.2

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an async issue, not getting called back.  I tend to open db in a plugin and store the handle inside hapi's internals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem:

The provided error is misleading. It's not the connection, it's the rethinkdb module! I import/require it in the main application and inside plugins. It's the same module, but a different instance of it. The connection itself is the same and still open.

Passing the connection AND the rethinkdb instance to plugins works. Passing the connection to plugins and using their rethinkdb does not. The connection must be from the same instance as later used to get data from the database.

Comment: It might be helpful to open an issue about the confusing error at https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues .

Comment: I am running rethinkdb in local machine and my code in same machine, on your comment I don't get exactly to fix ?

I use nodejs, rethinkdb lib